# After the mutiple imputation (MICE package in R), I still found that some variables are still with missing values. How to deal with it?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation, mice

I have a relatively large data set with around 12000 samples with 550 variables. Originally, I have around 800 variables, I used a rule that if missing rate in each variable is larger than 80% I will drop it that's why in the end I have 550 variables left. My vaariables are two types-categorcal and continous variales.

I tried two types of code to do multiple impuataion.

1. imputed<-mice(df,pred=quickpred(df, mincor = .3),m=5,seed=10)
2. imputed<-mice(df, m=5, method='cart', seed=10)

However, these two codes give me the same results that there are still some variables are still with missing value, althought most variables with missing values were impuated.

What should I do to deal with this situation?

Comment: See these links (https://datascienceplus.com/imputing-missing-data-with-r-mice-package/ ;  https://www.machinelearningplus.com/machine-learning/mice-imputation/   ). MICE is not a cure-all that always reliably fills in missing data.  Also, if you change the seed of the pseudo-random generator before each MICE run, such as using the current time-based millisecond from the computer's CPU, output results can vary slightly.  But statistical reviewers of papers will know this. It's usually adequate to state that was MICE was used, and then present the results.

Comment: @wjktrs Thank you!